# Saving a page and clicking on the save popup in chrome using AppleScript

Tags: google-chrome, applescript

I want to download a txt file, opened in a tab in chrome using AppleScript. I want the save as dialog of Mac to provide the default extension and the name of the file.

```
tell application "Google Chrome" to tell active tab of window 1 to save as "r1.txt"
```

I tried this approach, and some other approaches like

```
activate application "Google Chrome"
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "chrome"
        keystroke "s" using {command down}
        delay 1
        click button "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1
     end tell
end tell
```

still am not able to click the save button in the modal.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me using the latest version of Google Chrome and the latest version of MacOS Mojave

```
activate application "Google Chrome"
tell application "System Events"
    repeat while not (exists of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Chrome")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Chrome"
    repeat while not (exists of menu item 11 of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Chrome")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click menu item 11 of menu 1 of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of application process "Chrome"
    repeat while not (exists of UI element "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Chrome")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    click UI element "Save" of sheet 1 of window 1 of application process "Chrome"
end tell
```

Comment: _"You may need to adjust the delay values"_ Rather, you could improve the robustness of this script by testing for object existence instead of guessing how long it might take an object to be created.  It'll be slightly bulkier code but it would help promote good coding practice to newcomers learning from your example.

Comment: Point taken and agreed

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this problem was to try and avoid scripting the UI if possible, which can be problematic and unreliable.  Instead, I decided to use the shell command `curl` to do the downloading job for us instead of trying to manipulate *Chrome* into doing it.

All we need is the location of where to save the file to, which I've set as the location to which *Google Chrome* defaults to, namely `~/Downloads`.

```
property path : "~/Downloads" -- Where to download the file to

use Chrome : application "Google Chrome"
property sys : application "System Events"

property window : a reference to window 1 of Chrome
property tab : a reference to active tab of my window
property URL : a reference to URL of my tab

property text item delimiters : {space, "/"}

on run
    -- Stop the script if there's no URL to grab
    if not (my URL exists) then return false

    -- Path to where the file will be saved
    set HFSPath to the path of sys's item (my path)
    -- Dereferencing the URL
    set www to my URL as text
    -- Extract the filename portion of the URL
    set filename to the last text item of www

    -- The shell script to grab the contents of a URL
    set sh to the contents of {¬
        "cd", quoted form of the POSIX path of HFSPath, ";", ¬
        "curl --remote-name", ¬
        "--url", quoted form of www} as text


    ## 1. Download the file
    try
        using terms from scripting additions
            do shell script sh
        end using terms from
    on error E
        return E
    end try


    ## 2. Reveal the downloaded file in Finder
    tell application "Finder"
        tell the file named filename in the ¬
            folder named HFSPath to if ¬
            it exists then reveal it
        activate
    end tell
end run
```

It's a longer script than your present one, but most of it is declarations of variables (and properties), after which the script does two simple things:

1. Grabs the URL of the active tab in *Chrome*, and downloads the contents of that URL into the specified folder, retaining the same filename and extension as the remote file;
2. Once the download is complete, it reveals the file in *Finder*.